# C++ Qt creator can I comment each line, instead of commenting just the selection?

Tags: c++, qt

I think this question must have been asked before, but I couldn't find any.

So in Qt creator, let's say that I have some code like this:

```
int var1;
int var2;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    // do sth
}
```

When I select a bunch of lines from the beginning of the first line till the end of the last line and toggle comment, I get this:

```
// int var1;
// int var2;
// for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
//     // do sth
// }
```

But when I select from the middle of the first line, I get something like this:

```
int v/*ar1;
     ^ note the /*

int var2;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    // do sth
}*/
 ^ and */
```

What I would like is, have Qt creator comment using // from the beginning of each line selected, just like the first example.

Is there a way to do this? For all IDEs and editors I have used in the past (Atom, Sublime etc) this has worked, so I assume that there must be a way, but I can't seem to find it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can put a cursor where you want and type `//` to comment a line. It is not so complex, as hotkeys :). `/**/` block is used for commenting random parts of code

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is about how to type...

Comment: @DmitrySazonov I beg to differ. "Comment out the selected part of code" is a common function in IDEs, and those are definitely on-topic on SO. Also, doing this for a long selection is not something you can easily do by "typing."

Answer (score 2):

`Ctrl + /` will comment in/out the line the cursor happens to be on.

If you have a selection that spans over the entirety of one or more lines, the `//` comment will be generated as well.

But if your selection doesn't span over entire lines, the `/* */` format will be used.

That is very logical behavior that allows you to have both comment styles, depending on whether you want to comment out an entire line or just a small fragment. There is no benefit in losing the second commenting style, which can be quite useful at times, simply select lines end to beginning if you don't want the comment block style.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible in Qt Creator 10.0.0 you can do it in Edit/Preferences.../Text Editor/Behavior/Typing/Prefer single line comments. When enabled, it comments full lines instead of some portion of them.